# Linear power supply output voltage modification

Tags: power-supply

I recently got this "made in china" linear power supply which converts 220VAC/50Hz to 15VDC/1A.

Please see attached photo.

Would be possible to do some modifications to it so I can get 5VDC instead?

Ideally the changes should not introduce additional noise, since I'd like to use this psu in a low-noise application.

Efficiency reduction is acceptable, as far as I can get 500mA at the output.

Thanks[image]

Comment: If you could it would be very inefficient. If it's rated 15V 0.3A you would get 5V 0.3A. It would be better to use it as is, and add a 15V to 5V buck converter on its +15V output That could be expected to give you 5V 0.75A (0.9A minus buck conv efficiency)

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond, it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, Just a question: The buck converter would introduce extra noise? It's for a low noise application. Thanks

Comment: Yes it probably would. If current requirements are low enough I'd consider a linear regulator from 15 to 5V (LM317 etc) + additional LC filter if necessary

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond